# Why is the use of TAB (%09) characters in the middle a 'javascript:' URL valid?

Tags: web-browser, xss

Some context: I was assinged on a pentest and found an application that let me place my own links in an `a` tag's `href` attribute. As expected, all strange values like `javascript:` were correctly filtered by an XSS filter, however I discovered that you could bypass this filter by injecting a TAB character in the middle of the protocol specification like such:

```
<a href="javascri   pt:alert(1)"></a>
```

Now what I would like to know is, why do browsers accept this as a valid javscript URL which will happily execute code whereas other characters like SPACE character are not allowed? Is there a historic reason for them allowing this strange format?

---

**Note:** Tested on Chrome, for those that like to test it, it also works with `window.location` like so:

```
window.location.href = 'javascr\x09ipt:alert(1)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When an  element is clicked, the link is followed and its URL is
> resolved. This causes the string to be processed by the basic URL
> parser.
>
> In your example, the parameter is processed in the path state during
> which TAB (U+0009) characters, along with carriage return and line
> feed characters, are ignored, and therefore do not form part of the
> resolved URL.[Why does anchor tag remove tab character in URL specified inside href attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35412330)

[As per the specification](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-basic-url-parser) of Basic URL Parser, the ASCII tab or newline will be removed from the URL (or just ignored).

Answer (score 3):

I found an old discussion that you might find interesting for understanding the possible historical reasons behind this choice.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87298

That's a 19-year-old bug in Mozilla. The problem was that one website was not working as expected, because Mozilla didn't strip tab characters inside the URL in a link. The page worked as expected in Internet Explorer, which apparently ignored the tabs. Tabs are often used for indentation in HTML files, so sometimes you can expect a few tabs after a new line. Somebody cited a IETF standard suggesting that "whitespace should be ignored when extracting the URI". However, others were not fully convinced that removing all whitespace characters would be a good idea, because sometimes you might run across URIs with unencoded spaces (for example: `https://www.example.com/path with spaces/`), even though that would be wrong, at least according to current standards. Therefore they decided to just add tabs to the list of removed characters (carriage-return and line-feed characters were already being removed). Note though that spaces are allowed, and ignored, when they are at the beginning or at the end of the URI (example: `<a href="   http://www.example.com    "></a>`).

So I suppose the historical reason for this choice is that they wanted to make sure the following code would work:

```
<!-- URL with new lines and TABS for indentation -->
<a href="https://www.example.com/?
         param1=foo&
         param2=bar">
   Click on this example link
</a>

<!-- URL with unencoded spaces -->
<a href="https://www.example.com/path with spaces/foo">Click here</a>
```

However they did not check exactly where the spaces or tabs were in the URL, they just decided to keep the spaces and remove the tabs. As a result, the first example doesn't work if you use spaces for indentation, and tab characters can be included anywhere in the URL without affecting anything (so even `java<tab>script` will be ok).